# GIT: Should I clone as root or as cpanel user?

Tags: git, unix, permissions, centos, cpanel

I'm on a VPS with the latest Cpanel installed. I create a user from cpanel and ssh with that user to clone a repository. When I do that, I get Access denied or folder not writable errors when I try to view the site.

I changed permissions to 777 but nothing. Then when I chmod a folder to root:root it's fine.

Now my question is, Should I clone my repository as root user or as the site's user?

Comment: "When I do that": what? ssh to server or clone the repository?

Comment: When I clone the repo as the cpanel user and then try to view the site, I get writable permissions error. Mostly for assets and cache folders where files are dynamically generated

Comment: Permission are same that permission on git repo. When speak about "I get writable permissions error." it's referer to web site? Please extend your ask.